# VBScript Array issue

Tags: arrays, dynamic, vbscript

I'm trying to create a dynamic array to later use to get the median of several number values.  I have the following:

```
Dim DaysArray(), i, val1, val2

Sub BuildArray
    i = 0
    ...

    While Not recordset.EOF
        ReDim Preserve DaysArray(i)
        DaysArray(i) = recordset(value)
        i = i + 1
    Wend

    ...
End Sub

Sub ShowArrayValue
    ...

    Array.Sort(DaysArray)
    If DaysArray.Length Mod 2 <> 0 Then 
        Response.Write DaysArray(DaysArray.GetUpperBound(0)\2) 
    Else 
        val1 = DaysArray(DaysArray.Length\2)
        val2 = DaysArray((DaysArray.Length\2) - 1)
        Response.Write (val1 + val2)\2 
    End If
    ...
End Sub
```

However, during the first iteration thru the loop I get "Object required: Array"  on the Array.Sort(DaysArray) line?

Comment: If the recordset is an ADODB Recordset, you could also consider using the [`GetRows`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/getrows-method-ado?view=sql-server-2017) method return your data as 2-dimensional array automatically

Comment: The example makes no sense - `recordset.value`, somewhere in there you are missing a reference to the field - `recordset("thefieldname").Value`, assuming this is an `ADODB.Recordset` object reference.

Comment: The code you showed should raise that error with *every* iteration, b/c at no point in that code do you define an actual size for the array. `Dim DaysArray()` "defines" an array *without* size and should NEVER be used anywhere (as I discussed [here](https://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/dyn_vbs_arrays.shtml)). If you want a dynamically sized VBScript array: use `ReDim DaysArray(-1)` for defining an empty dynamic array, and then resize it in your loop e.g. like this: `ReDim Preserve DaysArray(UBound(DaysArray)+1)`. Beware of the inherent performance issues of this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`ReDim` Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/c850dt17%28v%3Dvs.84%29) e.g. as follows:

```
Dim DaysArray(), i, val1, val2

Sub BuildArray
i = 0
'...
While Not recordset.EOF
    ReDim Preserve DaysArray(i)
    DaysArray(i) = recordset.value
    recordset.MoveNext
    i = i + 1
Wend
'...
End Sub
```

> **ReDim Statement**
>
> Declares dynamic-array variables, and allocates or reallocates storage
>   space at procedure level.
>
> Syntax
>
> ```
> ReDim [Preserve] varname(subscripts) [, varname(subscripts)] . . .
> ```
>
> Arguments
>
> - `Preserve` Preserves the data in an existing array when you change the size of the last dimension.
> - `varname` Name of the variable; follows standard variable naming conventions.
> - `subscripts` Dimensions of an array variable; up to 60 multiple dimensions may be declared. The subscripts argument uses the following
>     syntax: `upper [,upper] . . .`
>
> The lower bound of an array is always zero.

Comment: Thanks JosefZ.  That got me past that error.  Now I'm getting an error "Object required: Array" on the line - Array.Sort(DaysArray) in the Sub ShowArrayValue.

Comment: @M.Hondros VBScript does not contain any native thing similar to [Array Object (Windows Scripting - JScript)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/k4h76zbx%28v%3dvs.84%29).